# Problem of removing protection of column in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have problem with protecting a column in Google Sheets.
I use the command to lock the column on a daily basis.
This is my code

```
//for first day
function lock_1() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('C6:C36').activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground('#cccccc');
var protection = spreadsheet.getRange('C6:C36').protect();
protection.addEditors(['ABC@co.jp']);
};
//the second day
function lock_2() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('D6:D36').activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground('#cccccc');
var protection = spreadsheet.getRange('D6:D36').protect();
protection.addEditors(['ABC@co.jp']);
};
.
.
.
function lock_30() {....}
```

At the start of a new month, i want unprotect to all column but not success
this is my code

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C7:AG36');
range.unprotect();
```

Is there a way to fix this problem.

[image: This is my table]

Comment: Does you sheet has range protections that  you wan to keep?

Answer (score 0):

I can do that thank you guys
this is code

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  var protection = protections[i];
  if (protection.canEdit()) {
  protection.remove();
}
```